# Erros de variáveis no início do PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal.
Com a ajuda do usuário [Luan Peil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/121284/luan-peil) eu consegui fazer meu algoritmo de um simulador de uma luta de RPG.
O problema é que ao iniciar, ele informa muitos erros de variável (Undefined).
Gostaria de saber se alguém saberia esconder essas mensagens ou então criar a variável antes de uma forma que não apareça durante o programa.

```
<?php
       if(isset($_GET["text"]))
{
 $gamestart=0;  

if($_GET["player"] != null) 
    { 
        $player = $_GET['player']; 
    } 
    else 
    {   
        $player = 100;
    }
if($_GET["enemy"] != null) 
    { 
        $enemy = $_GET['enemy'];
    } 
else    
{
    $enemy = 100; 
}
if($_GET["ecounter"] != null) 
    {
        $ecounter = $_GET['ecounter'];
    } 
else    
{
    $ecounter = 1; 
}

if($_GET["pcounter"] != null) 
    {
        $pcounter = $_GET['pcounter'];
    } 
    else    
    {
        $pcounter = 1; 
    } 
$dano = 15;

if(isset($_GET["action"])) {

if($ecounter <=3)
        {
            $action = rand(1, 4); 
        }

        else
        {
            $action = rand(1, 3);
        }


$ataque= $_GET["action"];

if($pcounter > 3 && $ataque== 4)
    {
        $ataque = 3;
    }


if($action == 1 && $ataque == 1) { //Se ambos atacarem
$dano =15;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $player -= $dano;
    echo "<br>Você deu um ataque no seu inimigo. causando 15 de dano";
    echo "<br>Ele te ataca de volta, causando 15 de dano.";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
} 
elseif($action == 1 && $ataque == 2) { //Se vc atacar e o inimigo defender
    $dano =15;
    $player -= $dano / 2;
    echo "<br>Você se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano";
    echo "<br>O inimigo te ataca, te dando 7,5 de dano.";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==1 && $ataque==3)
{
    $dano = 15;
    $player -= $dano;
    $player = $player + 30;
    if($player > 100)
    {
        $player = 100;
    }
    echo "<br>Ele te deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano.";
    echo "<br>Você tomou uma poção, recuperando os 15 de dano e mais 15 de vida";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==1 && $ataque==4)    
{
    $dano = 40;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $dano = 15;
    $player -= $dano;
    $pcounter++;
    echo "<br>Ele te deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano.";
    echo "<br>Você usou uma bola de fogo, causando 40 de dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action == 2 && $ataque == 1) { 
    $dano =15;
    $enemy -= $dano / 2;
    echo "<br>Você ataca o inimigo, mas ele recebe metade do dano por se defender";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
} 
elseif($action==2 && $ataque==2){ 
    echo "<br>Ambos se defenderam ao mesmo tempo, nada acontece.";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==2 && $ataque==3)
{
    $player = $player + 30;
    if($player > 100)
    {
        $player = 100;
    }
    echo "<br>Ele se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano.";
    echo "<br>Mas você tomou uma poção, recuperando 30 de vida e tornando o bloqueio inútil.";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==2 && $ataque==4)
{
    $pcounter++;
    $dano =40;
    $enemy -= $dano /2;
    echo "Você disparou uma bola de fogo";
    echo "<br>Ele se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==3 && $ataque==1)
{
    $dano = 15;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $enemy = $enemy + 30;
    if($enemy > 100)
    {
        $enemy = 100;
    }
    echo "<br>Você te deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano.";
    echo "<br>Ele tomou uma poção, recuperando 15 do dano e mais 15 de vida";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==3 && $ataque==2)
{
    $enemy = $enemy + 30;
    if($enemy > 100)
    {
        $enemy = 100;
    }
    echo "<br>Você se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano.";
    echo "<br>Mas ele tomou uma poção, recuperando 30 de vida.";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==3 && $ataque==3)
{
    $enemy = $enemy + 30;
    if($enemy > 100)
    {
        $enemy = 100;
    }
    $player = $player + 30;
    if($player > 100)
    {
        $player = 100;
    }
    echo"Ambos tomam uma poção, recuperando 30 de vida";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==3 && $ataque==4)
{
    $pcounter++;
    $dano = 40;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $enemy = $enemy + 30;
    if($enemy > 100)
    {
        $enemy = 100;
    }
    echo "Você usa uma bola de fogo, causando 40 de dano.";
    echo "O inimigo toma uma poção, recuperando 30 dos 40 de vida perdida";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==4 && $ataque==1)
{
    $ecounter++;
    $dano=40;
    $player -= $dano;
    $dano = 15;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $ecounter++;
    echo "<br> Você deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano";
    echo "<br> Ele deu um ataque muito forte, causando 40 de dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==4 && $ataque==2)
{

    $dano=40;
    $player -= $dano /2;
    $ecounter++;
    echo "Você se defende, recebendo metade do dano";
    echo "<br> Ele deu um ataque muito forte, causando 20 de dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==4 && $ataque==3)
{

    $dano=40;
    $player -= $dano;
    $player = $player + 30;
    if($player > 100)
    {
        $player = 100;
    }
    $ecounter++;
    echo "<br> Você tomou uma poção, recuperando 30 de vida";
    echo "<br> Ele deu um ataque muito forte, causando 40 de dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
elseif($action==4 && $ataque==4)
{

    $dano=40;
    $player -= $dano;
    $enemy -= $dano;
    $ecounter++;
    echo "Você disparou uma bola de fogo, causando 40 de dano";
    echo "<br> Ele deu um ataque muito forte, causando 40 de dano";
    echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
}
}

if($enemy <= 0) 
{
    echo '<br>você venceu o inimigo';
} 
elseif($player <= 0) 
{
    echo '<br>você perdeu para o inimigo';
} 
else 
{
    echo '
<form action="?" method="get">
    <br>1- ataque<br>
    2- defesa <br>
    3- tomar poção<br>
    4- bola de fogo<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="ecounter" value="'.$ecounter.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="pcounter" value="'.$pcounter.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="player" value="'.$player.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="enemy" value="'.$enemy.'"> 
    <input type="text" name="action">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>';
}   
}
?>
```

Erros indicados pelo phptester.net   :

NOTICE Undefined index: player on line number 18

NOTICE Undefined index: enemy on line number 24

NOTICE Undefined index: ecounter on line number 32

NOTICE Undefined index: pcounter on line number 40

Comment: Os erros são de variáveis não definidas ou de índices inexistentes no array?

Comment: Primeiro que eu não cheguei a fazer um array. Segundo que ao rodar o programa, ele informa que há um erro de variável não definida

Comment: `$_GET` é um array e ao fazer `$_GET['x'] != null` você assume que o índice x exista, o que pode não ser verdade. Poderia editar a pergunta e adicionar todas as mensagens de erros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu não estou enganado esse erro de undefined var na verdade é um `notice`.

Opções:

Se for mesmo o `notice` você pode configurar o php para suprimir

```
// No seu script.php
// Assim 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
// Ou assim
error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE);


// Ou no php.ini
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Ou você pode fazer as checagens assim

```
// Usar o isset antes
if( isset($test) )
{}

if( isset($_GET['test']) )
{}
```

Outra coisa que você também pode fazer e declarar no início essas variáveis que você esta iniciando dentro dos `if`, exemplo `$player=null;`

<sup>Update: Removida a segunda checagem `$test == null` pois como foi comentado por @DiegoSchmidt o `isset` já verifica.</sup>

Comment: Usar isso no IF para criar a variável e salvar seu valor? Seria isso?

Comment: Como exemplo veja esse if, ele é um dos que você deve colocar o `isset` antes `if($_GET["player"] != null)`

Comment: A variável ´$test´ seria uma variável que eu só precisaria substituir? ou seria uma nova para acrescentar ao código?

Comment: Ali é só um exemplo, é pq estou no celular. Você tem alterar os que estão sendo mostrados nos erros, `player`, `enemy`, `ecounter` e `pcounter`, os números das linhas deve levar ao `if`

Comment: Certo, agora que entendi, refiz o código com o exemplo que me passou e está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @riki481 Só uma correção, o isset já verifica se a varável é nula, não precisa fazer as duas checagens.

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt Certo, obrigado.