# Como envio incluindo o id da base de dados no email?

Tags: phpmailer

Tentei dessa maneira mas da undifined index.

basededados.php

```
<?php  

    $conexao=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','formulario');

    mysqli_set_charset($conexao,'utf');

    if ($conexao->connect_error) {
        die("Falha ao efectuar ligação: ".$conexao->connect_error);

    }
?>
```

envio.php

```
<?php 
  include "basededados.php";

  if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $processo=$_POST['processo']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $disciplina=$_POST['disciplina']; 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO dados VALUES ('','$nome','$processo','$email','$disciplina')";

    mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
 }

?>

<?php

    include "basededados.php";

    $mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
    $mailSub = $_POST['mailsub'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $escola=$_POST['escola']; 
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $processo=$_POST['processo']; 
    $disciplina=$_POST['disciplina']; 


   require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail ->IsSmtp();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail ->Port = 465; // or 587
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);                
   $mail ->Username = "user@gmail.com";
   $mail ->Password = "password";          
   $mail ->SetFrom("user@gmail.com");
   $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
   $mail ->Body='<h2>$id.Escola: '.$_POST['escola'].'<br>Nome: '.$_POST['nome'].'<br>Processo: '.$_POST['processo'].'<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>Disciplina: '.$_POST['disciplina'].$id.'</h2>';
   $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
       echo "Pedido não foi enviado.<br>";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Pedido enviado com sucesso!<br>";
   }
      $mail->ClearAddresses();
?>
```

Comment: Você quer o ID do insert que acabou de fazer e colocar no email?

Comment: sim mas tou tendo dificuldade em chama-lo

Comment: Se o erro é "undefined index" você está acessando uma posição que não existe de um array e não tem relação alguma com a conexão com o banco de dados ou enviar e-mail. Consegue elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: agora ta aparecendo undefined variable

Comment: Em relacão a esse notice `undefined` esse link talvez te ajude [Erros de variáveis no início do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369479/3774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Montei a resposta no exemplo que você postou,

Importante: Não inclua 2 vezes o mesmo arquivo.

a função `mysqli_insert_id($conexao)` retorna o id da ultima consulta feita pela conexão

```
<?php 
  include "basededados.php";

  if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $processo=$_POST['processo']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $disciplina=$_POST['disciplina']; 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO dados VALUES ('','$nome','$processo','$email','$disciplina')";

    mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

    $ultimo_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
 }

?>

<?php
    //Não pode incluir duas vezes o mesmo arquivo
    //include "basededados.php";
```

Comment: Era isso, queria saber como chamar o ultimo id obrigado